# Is there a way to get a variable or function from one file to another file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, import, blockchain

I have a file for my Blockchain called gale.js, and I need the Blockchain variable to get into my miner.js file:

```
let galeCoin = new Blockchain(); // My Blockchain
```

Can I access this variable from my miner.js file so I can run the `minePendingTransactions()` function from the `Blockchain` class

```
var galeCoin = /* the coin imported from the gale.js file */
var minerAdress = "0xOTUYboIUYEO5C274OUIYGo8isYOCYW6o87TO"; // SHA256 Hash for the miner
while (true) {
  minePendingTransactions(minerAdress); // mine (forever)
}
```

I would also like to access this variable in my `user.js` file:

```
var galeCoin = /* the coin imported from the gale.js file */
var userAdress = galeCoin.newAdress(); // A new adress for the user

// I will add the code here later...
```

And many other files!

But I can't seen to access the variable from the other files!
I tried this:

```
let galeCoin = new Blockchain();

export { galeCoin };
```

```
import { galeCoin } from './gale.js'
```

but that gives me this error when I run `miner.js` using `node miner.js`:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'gale.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/Movies/Desktop/devProjects/Blockchain/SecondTry/miner.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Movies/Desktop/devProjects/Blockchain/SecondTry/miner.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/Users/Movies/Desktop/devProjects/Blockchain/SecondTry/miner.js' ]
}
```

I dont understand the error message

I need help as soon as posible!

NOTE: My files are in `/Users/Movies/Desktop/devProjects/Blockchain/SecondTry/`

Comment: Are the files in the same directory?

Comment: @skara9. yes, they are in the same directory. (/Users/Movies/Desktop/devProjects/Blockchain/SecondTry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following to import galeCoin from `gale.js`:

```
var {galeCoin} = require('./gale.js');
```

You'll also need to export the galeCoin object from `gale.js`. You can use the following (append somewhere at the end of `gale.js`):

```
module.exports = {galeCoin};
```

Then you're going to want to run `npm install gale.js` to ensure that module is added to the `node_modules` directory. For this you're going to want to make sure the `node_modules` is in the same director as `miner.js`. If it is not, `npm -g install gale.js`.

I should note, I'm assuming you're using node.js, which from the error you threw, seems to be the case.

I hope this was helpful:)

Comment: Yes, I am using Node.js
But that code doesn’t work either!
Same error pops up in my terminal (maybe it is because I am using Mac OS?)

Comment: I revised it. Sorry about that, I hope it works this time around. Also it might be helpful if you include the contents of your directory in your question statement.

Comment: I found the problem!!! Sorry... I had `gale.js` in the `/Users/Movies/Desktop/devProjects/Blockchain/SecondTry/` directory, but `miner.js` was in `/Users/Movies/Desktop/devProjects/Blockchain/`! But your code helped me too! THANK YOU SOOOOOOOOOOO MUCH!!! :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :)

Comment: No problem at all! Glad you figured it out:)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
export let galeCoin = new Blockchain(); 
//add export statement at the beginning of the line where you declare your variable
```

You can read about it here: https://javascript.info/import-export

Comment: Thanks @Viktrix! But it still has the same error...